Error classifying image with TensorFlow Lite: "Label number 1 mismatch the shape on axis 1"
I'm working on an Android app that uses a TensorFlow Lite model for object detection. When I try to classify an image, I encounter the following error: Error classifying image: Label number 1 mismatch the shape on axis 1
Here is the relevant portion of my code:
    currentImageUri?.let { uri ->
        val imageStream: InputStream? = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)
        bitmap?.let { classifyImage(it) }
    }
}

private fun classifyImage(bitmap: Bitmap) {
    try {
        val model = Model.newInstance(applicationContext)

        val resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 640, 640, true)
        val image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(resizedBitmap)

        val outputs = model.process(image)
        val output = outputs.outputAsCategoryList

        val resultLabels = output.filter { it.score > CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD }
            .map { it.label }

        model.close()

        val intent = Intent(this, ListFoodActivity::class.java)
        if (resultLabels.isEmpty()) {
            intent.putExtra("noPrediction", true)
        } else {
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("resultLabels", ArrayList(resultLabels))
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e(TAG, "Error classifying image: ${e.message}")
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error classifying image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}


TensorFlow Lite Model Code Example:
val model = Model.newInstance(context)

// Creates inputs for reference.
val image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(bitmap)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(image)
val output = outputs.outputAsCategoryList

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
model.close() ```


What I've Tried:

Ensuring the input image is resized to 640x640, which matches the model's expected input size.
Filtering the output categories based on a confidence threshold.
Questions:

What does the error "Label number 1 mismatch the shape on axis 1" mean in this context?
How can I resolve this issue and correctly classify images using my TensorFlow Lite model?
Additional Information:

I'm using TensorFlow Lite for object detection in an Android application.
The model was converted to TensorFlow Lite format from a YOLOv8 model.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

